# How to copy this text from a webpage formatted?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to copy the all text from [this webpage](http://someonewhocares.org/hosts/) in a .txt on my Desktop.

The all text must be formatted like in the webpage.
I use this with no luck.

```
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();

File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\Matteo\Desktop\google2.txt",
    httpClient.GetStringAsync("http://someonewhocares.org/hosts/").Result);
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you'll need to save your file with a `.html` extension. Also, it seems that the webpage uses styles from a separate CSS file: http://someonewhocares.org/pollock.css
You'll need that grab that too to make it look like on the webpage.

Sample code:

```
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();

File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\Matteo\Desktop\index.html",
    httpClient.GetStringAsync("http://someonewhocares.org/hosts/").Result);
File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\Matteo\Desktop\pollock.css",
    httpClient.GetStringAsync("http://someonewhocares.org/pollock.css /").Result);
```

Comment: Actually now that I look you might not even need to get the css file as it's referenced with the file's absolute path.